# A tag keyword has taken on a new meaning: [deep-linking]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

A new user [just asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192338/deep-linking-with-facebook-twitter-etc) about deep-linking (the process of redirecting a link to an app rather than a browser), but the tag seems to be describing something completely different.

Currently, the [deep-linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/deep-linking) reads:

> In the World Wide Web, deep linking is the usage of ahyperlink that
>   is expressed as an absolute URL (i.e. http://example.com/path/page),
>   vs. a relative one (i.e. /path/page). Deep links to other web sites
>   can be desired or not by the site the link points to.

But Twitter ([as an example](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards/app-installs-and-deep-linking#deep-linking)) describes "deep linking" as:

> If a user [has] the application installed, you can specify a deep-link into the corresponding resource within your app.

Should we change the current tag description or create a new tag?

Comment: I don't think the Tag Wiki is correct.  That's an *absolute* URL, not a *deep-link* URL.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_linking) article describes a deep link as one that *"links to a specific, generally searchable or indexed, piece of web content on a website (i.e. http://example.com/path/page)"*, as opposed to the home URL of http://example.com.

Comment: Often, directly linking to any page of a web-site is encouraged and not seen as deep-linking, but deep-linking to the downloads provided / content used in those pages is discouraged or even forbidden.

Comment: Back in the old days lots of sites only wanted you to link to their homepage, not to deep linked content such as individual articles or products which was called deep linking (in fact when I first started making web pages it was considered polite to always ask before making a link to someone else's site period). That was deep linking. Later most sites realized it is way better (for sales, seo and stickiness) to have links to your, rich detailed content directly instead of requiring new visitors to make multiple clicks to get to it.

Comment: Can't say I've ever heard of twitter's use of deep linking.  To me a deep link is a direct link to the content of a website, rather than to the homepage.  Its been used like that for 15 years.

Comment: Looks like Facebook used the same term and then *retermed* it "App Linking": https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/app-links

Comment: To distance ourselves from facebook, how about *in-app-linking*?

Comment: [Google](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/) recently allowed app developers to deep link their apps (they also call it app indexing). So that might start to be used for Android questions as well.